# deck.gl ArcLayer with direction

Tags: svg, direction, deck.gl

Is it possible to draw an arrow or stick svg on the top of the arc (with z position) to represent a direction like below?

[image]

Comment: generally you can use markers to draw things like arrowheads on lines.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson. There is an IconLayer that deck.gl layer provides. But not sure on how to get the icons aligned with ArcLayer (Z ), so they will be attached to each Arc .